# roman-numbered backmatter in memoir

Tags: memoir, page-numbering

I use a `memoir` document and I would like to have to backmatter in roman numbers starting at I. From what I understand, I could at some point declare

```
\backmatter
\pagenumering{Roman}
```

but I prefer having all auch settings in the preamble. Therefore, I wonder whether this can be set for the entire `\backmatter`.

Comment: Then you have to modify the `\backmatter` definitions as per your wish...

Comment: Please advise if the Roman numerals should start over, i.e., show up as I, II, III, IV, etc or if you don't want to reset the page numbers.

Comment: I have added this, apologies!

Answer (score 1):

Save the definition of `\backmatter`, and then redefine `\backmatter`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\mybackmatter=\backmatter
\renewcommand{\backmatter}{\mybackmatter\pagenumbering{Roman}}
\begin{document}
  test
  \backmatter
  test
\end{document}
```